# Storing and using real-time user location

Tags: node.js, websocket, server, geolocation, real-time

My React Native app is connected to a Node.js server, and I’d like the server to be able to get the user’s location in real-time and check if it’s close to a different location.

I’m stuck on the real-time integration. The location part is similar to something like Lyft where user (driver’s for Lyft) locations are known in real-time and can be accessed by the server on-demand to perform calculations.

Are websockets like Socket.io the solution here, would storing the user’s location in a MongoDb database be a better approach, or something entirely different?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to do a real time processing of the location data of the user to analyze proximity to some landmark or like.

Rather than storing the location in database you can process it real time and discard, unless you want to have location history of the user (which also should be filtered to track certain artifacts).

If you have many users(like for B2C or C2C company does), you may want to use a streaming service like Kafka to operate directly on streams for calculating location proximity to the landmark.